# Formatting the legend on map created with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am using ggmap to create a map with points. The size of the point reflects the value of the variable.

```
mapPoints <- ggmap(map) + 
             geom_point(aes(x = Lat, y = Lon, size = KaskoAntal), 
               data = mydata, alpha = .7, colour = "#E32B2E") + 
             scale_size(range = c(2, 15))
```

The map looks good, but I would like to change a few things. I tried a lot of tutorials, but I haven't been able to find a solution to my the below issues:

1) I would like to  change the legend heading "KaskoAntal" to something else

2) I would like to format the numbers with thousand separator

3) Right now, the legend shows the following scale / bubble size: 100, 200, 300, 400.
   How can I control the scale?

Any help / leads are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basicly, `ggmap` package is based on `ggplot2, so look for `ggplot2` functions for changing specific element of graph i.e scale_colour_manual, scale_x_continuous. Plenty of them you find on docs.ggplot2.org.

Comment: This can also be an useful resource http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Thank you. The problem with the above tutorials / documentation is that they show how to change the X or Y. In my case X and Y are Latitude and Longitude.. But the variable that controls the size is KaskoAntal (Not on the axis).. So my question is: How can I change the legend for a plotted variable which is not on the X Y scale?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I would like to change the legend heading "KaskoAntal" to something else

Add `+ labs(size = "New name")`.

> 2) I would like to format the numbers with thousand separator

Add `+ scale_size_continuous(label=scales::comma)` (for KaskoAntal).

> 3) Right now, the legend shows the following scale / bubble size: 100, 200, 300, 400. How can I control the scale?

Add `+ scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(100, 200, 300, 400))`.

All of those changes of KaskoAntal's name, formatting, and bubble size refer to `size` because you defined `size = KaskoAntal`.